# Limit a templated function to base and derived types?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template base class like this:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class VectorT
{
public:
    typedef T data_type;
}
```

and a few specialised derived classes:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector2d : public VectorT<T, 2U>
{ // some specialised functions }

template<typename T>
class Vector3d : public VectorT<T, 3U>
{  // some other specialised functions }
```

and these work fine.  Howerver, I have a few free-standing functions for operators.  For example:

```
template<typename T, size_t Size>
VectorT<T, Size> operator*(T lhs, const VectorT<T, Size>& rhs)
{
    ... 
}
```

Unfortunately these do not work for my derived classes, because they return a `VectorT<T, Size>` instead of a `Vector2d<T>`.

So I tried with

```
template<V>
V operator*(typename V::data_type lhs, const V& rhs)
{
    ... 
}
```

and this works fine, however it can lead to ambiguities because it sucks in anything else with a data_type member.

How can I get around this: how can I write type safe functions that only work with my vector base, or any derivatives of?

I am trying to get around having to re-declare and redefine the operators again for the subclasses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add yet another base class, one that is independent of the template parameters, and use [**SFINAE**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to disable calls for types other than derived from such base:

```
struct VectorBase {};

template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
class VectorT : public VectorBase { ... }

template< typename V >
typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_base_of< VectorBase, V >, V >::type
operator*( V lhs, V const& rhs ){ ... }
```

Note that `is_base_of< X, X >` is always `true`, so this function will work for one more type than required, namely the base class `VectorBase`.

If you are using a compiler that implements TR1, you can replace `boost::` for `std::` in both places where is used.

Comment: Thank you, this is the second time tonight you have given me an answer involving SFINAE; I think this is where the gaps in my knowledge lie!  I am not sure exactly how enable_if works yet, but this has worked really well.  Thank you again.

Comment: @Kballo: regarding replacing `boost::` by `std::` --> note that `std::enable_if` is a strict equivalent for `boost::enable_if_c`, therefore you would have to "unwrap" the `value` member of `is_base_of` yourself when switching to `std::`.

Answer (score 1):

You are in an unusual situation out of which there is no "nice" way. You can:

1. Check the type at runtime (or compile time, boost can probably do that)
2. Take a `VectorT<>&` and use that instead of creating a new `VectorT` inside the function and returning it. This way you can take subclasses of `VectorT` by reference as well. That would make you have to use a function instead of an operator though.
3. Do what K-ballo said.